# document.getElementById(...).setAttribute('style',... not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

document.getElementById(...).setAttribute('style',... is not working in Internet Explorer 7.0. How can I make this work in Internet Explorer?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myarray=new Array(3);
    for (i=0; i <1000; i++){
        myarray[i]=new Array(3);
    }
    myarray[0][0]="new"; myarray[0][1]="old";

    function swapText(id){
        document.getElementById('id' + id).setAttribute('style', 'font-weight: bold; color: red; font-size:150%;');
        document.getElementById('id'+ id).innerHTML = myarray[id][0];
    }
    function originalText(id){
        document.getElementById('id' + id).setAttribute('style', 'color:' + 'black'  + ';');
        document.getElementById('id' + id).innerHTML = myarray[id][1];
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="scoreboard" border='1'> </div>
    <div id="qa">
        <div id="col1" class="column">  
            <div id="id0" onmouseover="swapText(0)"; onmouseout="originalText(0)">old</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you have some javascript error on this code?

Comment: doesn't really answer the questions, but you should but those css rules in a class or two, and then just add the class.

Comment: David, there are no errors. However, in IE, the style affects don't work... the words change in IE (from 'old' to 'new' and back), but the style changes don't work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using `setAttribute` is unreliable if you want the change to be reflected in the document.  Use [`Element.style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536498%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instead:

```
var el = document.getElementById('id' + id);
el.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
el.style.color = 'red';
el.style.fontSize = '150%';
```

and suchlike.

Comment: It's the best solution, I guess. Is compatible with all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/).

jQuery is a very powerful JavaScript library that lets you do almost anything with very little code. One of its main advantages (except for its beautiful syntax) is that *it is specifically designed to be platform- and browser-independent*, so you shouldn't have to worry about any of that anymore.

Doing the same thing you do now, but in jQuery, could look something like this:

```
function swapText(id) {
    $('#id' + id)
        .css('font-weight','bold').css('color','red').css('font-size','150%')
        .html(myarray[id][0]);
}

function originalText(id) {
    $('#id' + id).css('color','black').html(myarray[id][1]);
}
```

Of course, if you define a CSS class for your "swapped" style, you could simply use `$('#id'+id).addClass('swapped');` and `$('#id'+id).removeClass('swapped');`.

Also, there are really nice ways to hook up events, so you don't even need to define the functions with names if you don't want to:

```
$('div').hover(function() { 
    $(this)
        .css('font-weight','bold').css('color','red').css('font-size','150%')
        .html(myarray[id][0]);
}, 
function() { 
    $('#id' + id).css('color','black').html(myarray[id][1]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas.  I have been putting off learning jQuerry for way to long.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534651%28v=VS.85%29.aspx): *This attribute is not accessible through scripting. To access styles through scripting, use the style object*

Answer (score 0):

you can use setAttribute that is also compatible with IE-8 and IE-7

```
 var el = document.getElementById('id' + id);
 el.setAttribute('fontWeight','bold');
 el.setAttribute('color','red');
 el.setAttribute('fontSize','150%');
```

for assigning a class to an element, i suggest following

```
 el.className = "class-name";
```