# javascript return by ajax does not work

Tags: javascript, ajax

the requested page returns the following javascript by jsp:

```
<%!
String test = "hello world!!";
String test3 = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.getElementById(\"content\").setAttribute(\"style\",\"color:red\");</script>";
out.println(test3);
%>
```

and in the ajax page, i extracted the expression btw  and uses

```
eval((e)())
```

in which e is the javascript returned, and the HTML is like:

```
<div id="content">
<p>hello world!</p></div>
```

but apparently the javascript returned does not work, is something wrong with the code? thanks
by the way, i'm not allowed to use jQuery...

Comment: Due to security reasons, you should never use ´eval´ function

Comment: The bigger issue here is your writing JavaScript in server side code then passing it through eval.

Comment: Instead, you could load your script in a container with JQuery ´load´ function for example : https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: what is the problem with the javascript? it returned correctly but just not work

Answer (score 0):

eval() takes in a single parameter: the Javascript code as a string, such as -

```
eval(e)
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.ASP.

Comment: yes, i passed the javascript expression as a string to the eval(), but it doesn't work

Comment: What is the exact javascript expr you are trying to eval?

Comment: change the color of the element with id "content".

Comment: Assuming your expression is valid (you didn't post the -actual- JS only expr used with eval) and the HTML is valid, then it could be a browser issue: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065609/document-getelementbyid-setattributestyle-not-working-in-internet-ex