# How to add an image in javascript with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, image, switch-statement

How do you make this have a result which is an image, not text

```
switch(true){
    case (a>b):document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="hey";
                                      break;
```

Comment: `.innerHTML = '<img src="">';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're adding an image to the DOM

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<img src="path/to/image" />';
```

If result is an image element

```
document.getElementById('result').setAttribute('src', 'path/to/image');
```

Comment: then how do you style the image?

Comment: Use Element.setStyle.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6065647/320417 for an example.